# Can I use razor with framework 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an aplication using MVC 4 with the framework 4.5, need to downgrade the framework to 4.0, but it seems like razor won't work with the framework 4.0

Comment: `Razor` is supported from `MVC3`. If your application is in `MVC3` or upper, you can use razor.

Comment: The version of Razor you have installed may not be compatible with .NET 4.0. Take a look at your NuGet packages and see if you can't roll them back to an earlier version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the information of .Net FrameWork support razor:

```
.NETFramework 4.0
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (= 2.0.30506)
.NETFramework 4.5
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (>= 3.0.0)
```

To install RazorEngine, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.9.3
```